# How do I Convert XSL-FO to CSS3?

Tags: css, xsl-fo

I have a XSL-FO file

```
 <fo:layout-master-set>
 <fo:simple-page-master master-name="cover"
 page-height="11in"
 page-width="8.5in"
 margin-top="1in"
 margin-bottom="1in"
 margin-left="1in"
 margin-right="1in"
 font="12pt Times">

 </fo:simple-page-master>

 <fo:simple-page-master master-name="leftPage"
 page-height="11in"
 page-width="8.5in"
 margin-left="1.5in"
 margin-right="1.5in"
 margin-top="1in"
 margin-bottom="1in"
 font="10pt Verdana">
 </fo:simple-page-master>

 <fo:simple-page-master master-name="rightPage"
 page-height="11in"
 page-width="8.5in"
 margin-left=".75in"
 margin-right=".75in"
 margin-top="1in"
 margin-bottom="1in"
 font="10pt Courier">
 </fo:simple-page-master>

</fo:layout-master-set>
```

How can I convert or re-write this code to CSS3?

I was unable to find this information anywhere on the web. I think it can be done manually with little work but I'm still learning to understand CSS and XML/etc. I'm a bit surprised I couldn't find a simple conversion program. Thanks.

UPDATE: After taking the first answer into consideration I instead did research on the equivalent CSS3 code instead of trying to do a conversion and this is what I ended up with:

```
@page{
   size: 11in 8.5in;  
}

@page:cover{ 
   margin: 1in;
   font: 12pt Times;
}

@page:right{ 
   margin-left: 1.5in;
   margin-right: 1.5in;
   margin-top: 1in;
   margin-bottom: 1in;   
   font: 12pt Verdana;
}

@page:left{ 
   margin-left: .75in;
   margin-right: .75in;
   margin-top: 1in;
   margin-bottom: 1in;   
   font: 12pt Courier;
}
```

Any further input about this would be appreciated. Would this CSS3 be considered the equivalent to the XSL-FO I posted?

Answer (score 2):

While it should be doable, files are usually not converted from XSL-FO to CSS. 
An XSL-FO file contains both content and formatting. CSS splits that into 2 files: an HTML file that contains the content, and a CSS file that contains the formatting.

So generally, it's easier to use the source file that was used to create the XSL-FO. That source file has to be converted to HTML, then you can apply a CSS.